# mhtml file not loading/displaying properly in webview for lollipop and marshmallow but on pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, webview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, mhtml

I have a .mhtml file in my database as byte array. I have written below code and its working fine in pre-lollipop devices. But it is not working on lollipop and marshmallow.

**Code:-**

```
       String path = filepath.getAbsolutePath()+"/StudyWellAppv5/"+fname;
       byte[] bytes = tblK.gethtmlFile();
       try {
           if (!file.exists()) {
               file.createNewFile();
           }
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(bytes);
           webview.loadUrl("file://" + path);
          }
          catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
```

**Runtime permission code:-**

```
/Permission to read and write from external storage
   private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
   private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
           Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   };


int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
       int readpermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
       if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED||readpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // We don't have permission so prompt the user
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                   getActivity(),
                   PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                   REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           );
       }
```

**Error Log :-**

```
"Blocked script execution in 'file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (1618)
06-16 13:48:42.571 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1618)] "Blocked script execution in 'file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (1618)
06-16 13:48:42.598 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/EC2C4CD1/1_files/image002.jpg", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (0)
06-16 13:48:42.599 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/EC2C4CD1/1_files/image004.jpg", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (0)
06-16 13:48:42.599 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/EC2C4CD1/1_files/image006.jpg", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (0)
06-16 13:48:42.671 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/EC2C4CD1/1_files/image008.jpg", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (0)
06-16 13:49:10.182 1244-1244/com.samji.StudyWellAppv5 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/StudyWellApp/2016-06-16%2001-48-42.mhtml (0)
```

Note:-This code is working perfectly on pre-lollipop devices. It is not working only on lollipop and marshmallow.

Comment: have you get runtime permissions?

Comment: yes, please check updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get runtime permission for API 23 (marshmallow)

**Example Code:**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //SomeStuffWhichNeedPermission(); dont call here directly wihtout permission in 6.0 do like below
            checkPremission();
        }

        void SomeStuffWhichNeedPermission() {
            // storing data code here now
            String path = filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/StudyWellAppv5/" + fname;
            byte[] bytes = tblK.gethtmlFile();
            try {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(bytes);
                webview.loadUrl("file://" + path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        void checkPremission() {
            //select which permission you want
            final String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            // if in fragment use getActivity()
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityName.this, permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                // you have permission go ahead
                SomeStuffWhichNeedPermission();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                    final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                    final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                            && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                    if (isGranted) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                        SomeStuffWhichNeedPermission();
                    } else {
                        // you dont have permission show toast
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please check my updated question. I already have runtime permission code.

Comment: @Sam  have you seen permission dialog after adding new code?